# 0-12V square wave to linear 12V

Tags: wave, linear

Can anyone help me with the design of circuit?

I need to use a zero to 12V square wave input and output a linear or straight 12V to carry 2 amperes.
I think a collection of capacitors and an inductor will be part of the design.

The source signal is 12v/ground PWM. I want to use this to simultaneously provide 12V power supply feed to the load and also to provide PWM signalling to the load. ("Power over PWM")

Adding information from "answer":

I want to use the square wave zero to 12 v as a source. And have a smooth 12v output from that. I installed one a couple of years ago that was made by a pretty clever guy, but I would like to be able to reproduce the circuit board myself. It was for a reverse camera in a car and the reverse lamp signal was PWM. This caused the camera to lose voltage constantly and the video to be poor quality. This guy made this board that had the 12v PWM input and output was a stable 12v when viewed on scope. This worked great with only the 4 wires and didn't require a dedicated power feed to be run through the car.

Comment: Not clear what you mean with "linear or straight 12 V"? This sounds like you always want constant 12 V output, and that would mean you just ignore your input and use a 12 V power supply. I don't think that's what you meant, but it is the best I can guess from your description! Could you maybe make a proper labeled drawing of the voltage vs time of your input and output signals in the same time/amplitude diagram? Hand-drawn and well-photographed is fine as long as clean!

Comment: use a retriggerable one shot to enable the 12 V supply ... that way the 12 V output is enabled whenever the pulse train is present

Comment: Why the PWM in the first place?

Comment: **ALL COMMENTERS** - the op wants to use a 12v/0V PWM signal as both  a 12V DC power source AND a PWM signalling source over the same wires.

Comment: In order to size the filter capacitor, you should test the camera to check the lowest voltage it will still run at, and measure how much current it uses.

Comment: Sandro's answer will probably work OK. If not we can provide a solution that will.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 12 V PWM signal capable of rather high current, and you want to use it to get stable a stable 12V DC voltage with 2 A capacity.

If rather stable is enough (and the consumption of the camera is also rather stable), then the easiest solution might be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZWmt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you have to choose a suitable diode (I would advise a Schottky diode (i.e. low voltage drop), rated with 10 A+ continuous current).

The resistor might or might not be needed, depending on the resistance of your cable, of the diode, and of the capacitor (ESR). If your resistances are too low, you might blow your fuse by not adding it.

The most tricky part will be the capacitor, that will need to be huge. How huge depends on the current drawn by the camera, and the frequency/duty cycle of your PWM signal. It might be a game killer if you really need 2 A and your PWM is slow.

The result will be a DC voltage a few volts bellow 12 V (by how much depends on the current drawn, and the resistances involved), with some variations left (the bigger the capacitor, and the higher the PWM frequency, the less variations)

If the resulting voltage is too low, adding a DC/DC converter (boost converter) at the output will give you back a stable 12 V.

If your PWM frequency is too low, then you might end needing too big capacitors for this to work. In this case, I think you will need to build something around a small battery.

Comment: Thanks, I will see what is available from Jaycar and my own stock of components and put something together.I will report back with the results.

Comment: I would advise you first check the frequency (and if possible the duty cycle) of PWM signal. And also please check the fuse rating for this circuit. From there, we can calculate correct values for the components (in particular the capacitor). If you take a random capacitor you have in stock, it's quite unlikely that it will work (depending on the PWM frequency, you will probably need at least 1mF (already big), maybe 100mF or more (huge)

Comment: @Sandro  The diode should be*at least* 2 x 1N400x in parallel, or a higher current device. (The 1N4148 would die very rapidly). || As you note, the PWM frequency affects the filter capacitor size. || It's POSSIBLE that the source PWM is not capable of supporting a 2A load and that it needs a suitably capable source PWM switch as well. (From what the OP says the tx end was OK originally).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : I just kept the default diode. But I specified in the text how to select one. For the load, I suppose it is capable of supplying this current, as otherwise the current solution woldn't haved worked. Being automotive, I wouldn't be surprised if it is just a relay switching the battery. But as long as OP don't provide the required information, I can only sketch a solution, not do a full design

Comment: @Josh Jaycar: D1 - 1N5408 ZR1018 3A (1000V) - probably OK.  Two in parallel better BUT almost certainly not needed. || 1N5404 ZR1014 - similar || 6A10 ZR1024 6A (1000V) || Average current is 2A max SO a 3A diode is probably very OK. || Low frequency and/or low duty cycle PWM will increase peak currents. Knowing the frequency of the PWM would help a lot . BIG cap smooths things better. || R1 reduces initial surge to protect fuse and switch. R1 drops 1V at 2A as shown - value of DC MAY be less important than absolute smoothness.

Comment: @Sandro  No criticism intended. Your answer will probably work. It depends on how much ripple and lowest V that the camera can tolerate. || IF it's not good enough then an active regulator will work (as I know you know).